# What dotnet runtime version is being used by my Azure Function?

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-durable-functions, azure-functions-runtime

I have an Azure Durable Function running on Azure. It has:

- FUNCTIONS_EXTENSION_VERSION: "~3",
- FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME: "dotnet"

We are experience an error that I have found previously [reported](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/1094) on the dotnet/runtime repo. The issue has since been fixed ([1](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/pull/32149) [2](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/pull/42870)) and the fix was [released in version 3.1.4](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/pull/42870#issuecomment-609932010). However we are still seeing the error which makes me think the runtime in use is an older build. I can't find any information about which minor/patch version of the runtime is in use on the VM that actually executes our function.

Is there a way to figure this out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Function apps run in and are maintained by, the Azure App Service platform. As such, your function apps have access to most of the features of Azure's core web hosting platform including Advanced tools (Kudu) and Console:

[image]

Probably the easiest way to figure out the version is to open the console and type
`dotnet --version`

[Read more about how to access the console](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-how-to-use-azure-function-app-settings?tabs=portal&WT.mc_id=AZ-MVP-5003203#console)